# Getting the average on a group with a higher population

Tags: tcl, average, mean, pca

As highlighted in blue, I am trying to calculate the average (X, Y) of a group with more significant data points compared with other groups in a dataset. If I take the entire dataset's average, we get every group's average (X, Y), as highlighted in orange.

Is there a simple way to know which group has a higher population and then take the average just for that group?

I am doing this in Tcl, so I hope the general method you suggested can be applied in Tcl. Thank you!

[image]

EXAMPLE DATASET:

```
X    Y
1    9
1.5  8.5
0.5  9.5
1.5  9.5
1    9.5
0.5  8.5
1.5  9
0.5  9
0    9
0    8.5
2    9
1.7  8.7
1.2  9.2
0.2  9.2
0.7  8.3
1    8
8.5  1.5
9.5  0.5
8.5  0.5
9    1.5
9.5  0
8    0
9    0.5
```

Comment: The data points in the two groups are nicely separated. I could imagine running K-means with K=2, determining the membership of each point, and taking an average over the elements of the group with the most members.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure from my comment above indeed seems to work. A hasty implementation in Python is

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

# Data set
data = np.array([
[1,    9],
[1.5,  8.5],
[0.5,  9.5],
[1.5,  9.5],
[1,    9.5],
[0.5,  8.5],
[1.5,  9],
[0.5,  9],
[0,    9],
[0,    8.5],
[2,    9],
[1.7,  8.7],
[1.2,  9.2],
[0.2,  9.2],
[0.7,  8.3],
[1,    8],
[8.5,  1.5],
[9.5,  0.5],
[8.5,  0.5],
[9,    1.5],
[9.5,  0],
[8,    0],
[9,    0.5]])

# Cluster prediction
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(data)
print(kmeans.labels_)

# Analysis
print("Number of points in cluster with label 0:", sum(kmeans.labels_==0))
print("Number of points in cluster with label 1:", sum(kmeans.labels_==1))
print("Mean of coordinates for elements with label 0: (",
    sum(data[kmeans.labels_==0,0])/sum(kmeans.labels_==0), ",",
    sum(data[kmeans.labels_==0,1])/sum(kmeans.labels_==0), ")")
print("Mean of coordinates for elements with label 1: (",
    sum(data[kmeans.labels_==1,0])/sum(kmeans.labels_==1), ",",
    sum(data[kmeans.labels_==1,1])/sum(kmeans.labels_==1), ")")
```

The printed output is (I'm too tired right now to make a nice plot):

```py
Number of points in cluster with label 0: 16
Number of points in cluster with label 1: 7
Mean of coordinates for elements with label 0: ( 0.9249999999999998 , 8.9 )
Mean of coordinates for elements with label 1: ( 8.857142857142858 , 0.6428571428571429 )
```

Comment: I see you have parameterized n_clusters =2. It seems to work for this simple example. What if the dataset is more complicated for many more groups? There is always one group with a higher population, and we want to get the average of that particular group.

Comment: That's not tcl...

Comment: @Kuo-Hsien Chang The number of groups is not really critical (but maybe more starting points of the clustering algorithm should be tried). It's more important to have a clear group structure in the data  and to have a good choice of the number of groups. K-means clustering iteratively improves the means of the clusters. If clusters are difficult to separate, then you might encounter convergence issues.

Comment: @Shawn You are absolutely right. However, the question also mentioned that a general approach which is available in tcl would suffice. Unfortunately, I do not have any programming experience in tcl but I would be very surprised if tcl does not feature some sort of clustering algorithm. If it does, then the above steps will work,  so (1) run clustering algorithm, (2) predict labels for each point (i.e. assign the label of the nearest clustering point), and (3) count and average over points with the same labels.

Comment: I found this https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Clustering+data Perhaps it could be used for this purpose.

Comment: @Kuo-Hsien Chang. Yes, the link you provide will indeed do the trick as an implementation of KMeans clustering is readily available from your link. If you are familiar with tcl (which I am unfortunately), then it should be easy to translate my Python code above almost line-by-line.

Comment: @Hanno Reuvers. Is there a way to know which element is within the largest group? In this case, it is the element with label 0.

Comment: Is there a way to determine reasonable n_clusters? What if we don't know how many clusters might be in a dataset? (But, we do know the total data points!)